# Extension of Sass file modified by Gulp

Tags: css, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm encountering a very weird problem with **gulp-sass**. Earlier this week, my gulp sass task ran as expected, compiling the sass into css and ending the task. But for these past few days, my gulp sass runs and hangs, and SourceTree shows no changes in the css files when the sass files are edited. Then I installed **gulp-debug** to debug the file paths, and the file path to `proverbs_everyday.scss` keeps getting modified to `proverbs_everyday.css`. What's causing this and how do I resolve it? My system is Windows 10.

Btw, I'm still relatively new to SASS.

Output

```
C:\wamp64\www\proverbs_everyday_admin\resources>gulp minify-css
[10:01:10] Using gulpfile C:\wamp64\www\proverbs_everyday_admin\resources\gulpfile
.js
[10:01:10] Starting 'minify-css'...
[10:01:10] Finished 'minify-css' after 10 ms
[10:01:10] css_path pe\src\css\proverbs_everyday.min.css
[10:01:10] css_path pe\src\css\styles_admin_main.min.css
[10:01:10] css_path pe\src\css\styles_parsley.min.css
[10:01:10] css_path 3 items

C:\wamp64\www\proverbs_everyday_admin\resources>gulp sass
[10:02:50] Using gulpfile C:\wamp64\www\proverbs_everyday_admin\resources\gulpfile
.js
[10:02:50] Starting 'sass'...
[10:02:50] sass_path pe\src\sass\proverbs_everyday.css
[10:02:50] sass_path 1 item
```

Gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var del = require('del');

const NODE_PATH = './node_modules/';
const VENDOR_PATH = './vendor/';

const SASS_PATH = "./pe/src/sass/proverbs_everyday.scss";
const CSS_PATH = "./pe/src/css/**/*.css";
const COMPILED_CSS_PATH = "./pe/dist/css";


gulp.task('default', ['update-vendor', 'update-css', 'watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function()
{
    gulp.watch(SASS_PATH, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(CSS_PATH, ['minify-css']);
});

// === manage styles started ===
gulp.task('update-css', ['clean-css', 'minify-css']);

gulp.task('clean-css', function()
{
    del.sync([
        COMPILED_CSS_PATH,
        CSS_PATH,
        '!' + COMPILED_CSS_PATH,
        '!' + CSS_PATH
    ])
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function()
{
    gulp.src(CSS_PATH)
        .pipe(clean_css({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(debug({title: 'css_path'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(COMPILED_CSS_PATH));
});

gulp.task('sass', function()
{
    gulp.src(SASS_PATH)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(debug({title: 'sass_path'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_PATH));
});
// === manage styles end ===
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "proverbs_everyday",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Proverbs Everyday",
  "main": "../index.php",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "proverbs-everyday",
    "proverbs",
    "everyday"
  ],
  "author": "Davina Leong",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.6.0",
    "sb-admin-2": "^3.3.8"
  }
}
```

---

Main SCSS

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'mixins';

body {
  background: $bg-body;
  color: $colour-body;
}

.navbar-default {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  @include clear-border;
  color: $colour-navbar;
  font-family: $font-tillitium-web;

  .navbar-brand {
    @include navbar-link($colour-navbar);

    img {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }

  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    @include navbar-link($colour-navbar);

    .visible-sm,
    .visible-xs {
      display: inline;
    }
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    @include clear-border;

    .icon-bar {
      background-color: $colour-navbar;
    }

    &:hover {
      background: none;

      .icon-bar {
        background-color: darken($colour-navbar, 20%);
      }
    }

    &:link,
    &:active,
    &:focus,
    &:visited {
      @extend .navbar-toggle;
    }
  }
}

#search-form {
  .form-group > .form-control {
    background: transparentize($colour-navbar, 0.8);
    border: thin solid darken($colour-navbar, 20%);
    border-radius: 0;
    color: $colour-navbar;
    font-family: $font-tillitium-web;

    option {
      color: $colour-body;
    }

    @include placeholder {
      color: $colour-navbar;
    }
  }

  .btn-navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: thin solid darken($colour-navbar, 20%);
    color: $colour-navbar;
    background: transparentize($colour-navbar, 0.8);

    &:hover {
      border-color: $colour-navbar;
      background: transparentize($colour-navbar, 0.6);
    }

    &:focus {
      border-color: $colour-navbar;
    }

    &:active {
      @extend .btn-navbar;
    }
  }
}

.header {
  background: $bg-header;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

@for $index from 1 through 3 {
  h#{$index} {
    color: $colour-heading;
    font-family: $font-arapey;
  }
}

@for $index from 4 through 6 {
  h#{$index} {
    color: $colour-heading;
    font-family: $font-tillitium-web;
  }
}

#passage_table {
  min-height: 500px;

  #passage {
    color: $colour-passage-text;
    font-family: $font-handlee;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}

a {
  color: $colour-link;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    color: lighten($colour-link, 20%);
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &:link,
  &:active,
  &:focus,
  &:visited {
    @extend a;
  }
}

.disabled-link {
  color: $colour-link-disabled;
  cursor: default;

  &:link,
  &:active,
  &focus,
  &:visited {
    @extend .disabled-link;
  }
}

.chevron-link {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55%;

  .chapter-no {
      font-family: $font-tillitium-web;
      font-size: 12pt;

      .chapter-no-xs {
          font-size: 8pt;
      }
  }
}

.date {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: $colour-heading;
  font-family: $font-tillitium-web;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(219, 209, 182, 0.5);

  p {
    color: lighten($colour-heading, 30%);
    font-family: $font-tillitium-web;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

There are no imports in `variables.scss` and `mixins.scss`.

Comment: You have a glob (const CSS_PATH = "./pe/src/css/**/*.css";) as your 'sass' task gulp.dest(CSS_PATH));    Globs are not permitted in gulp.dest.  If you just give it a simple path is your issue fixed?

Comment: ooh... haha... that might make sense....